# Как правильно работать с mysql в nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

У меня есть приложение которое работает многопоточно. И мне нужно заносить из каждого потока записи в бд.

Для этого я создал такую функцию:

```
async insert(...) {
    var con = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: this.mysqlData['host'], user: this.mysqlData['user'], password: this.mysqlData['pass'], database: this.mysqlData['base']
    });

    var sql = "INSERT INTO `"+this.mysqlData['tableWithdrawal']+"` (date, dayName, hour, amount, status, message) VALUES ('"+date+"', '"+dayName+"', '"+hour+"', '"+amount+"', '"+status+"', '"+message.trim()+"')";
    await con.query(sql);

    await con.end();
}
```

Получается что каждый раз создается соединение с бд (*createConnection*), и после выполнения запроса соединение закрываем (*con.end()*)

Насколько это правильно? Учитывая то что в каждом потоке нужно сделать в среднем 100 записей в бд, а потоков может быть много (до 100).

Comment: А что мешает сначала набрать эти 100 записей, а потом одним пакетом записать в таблицу?

Comment: **MySQL** поддерживает пул соединений с БД. Создайте такой пул соединений и в таком случае каждый раз открывать/закрывать соединение с БД не надо будет

Comment: попробуйте этот пакет, там есть пул соедениней, воможно вам будет полезным https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-connection-pools